# Where are the methods in object created using class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, object

Assuming there is a class that has both property and method(s). When creating objects from this class using the new keyword and let's say printing on the console, it shows just the property name in the object, why are the methods now showing up? I can access the methods in the code.

Sample code,

```
class A {
  propA = true;
  methodA() { return true; }
  methodB() { return true; }
}

console.log("Object of A -> ", new A());
// Object of A ->  A { propA: true }
```

P.S. I am using typescript

Comment: a) they are non-enumerable b) they are inherited from the prototype. `new A` does not create any methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access to the prototype and then get the properties

Sample code here:

```
class A {
  propA = true;
  methodA() { return true; }
  methodB() { return true; }
}

console.log("Object of A -> ", Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(new A())));
//Object of A -> ["constructor", "methodA", "methodB"]
```

Comment: Great. But can you explain why does it happen?

Comment: So, the instance you are creating is like an object and if you print that you will get all the attributes, since you want to get the methods it contains, you need to get the prototype of the class (more info about prototype here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) and then you can access to the properties from the class and not from the instance. you can read more about reflection here: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-reflection/